# Can a well-conditioned person sit up using only their core?

Tags: core, posture

When lying down and needing to sit up, I either push myself up with an elbow, or bring my knees to my chest and then kick out, creating the momentum to propel myself up off the couch. I checked a yoga book at the library and saw that sitting up without hooking your toes under something is called a "roll-up". Is this a widely attainable skill?

My motivation for the question is that I have difficulty just sitting up straight on the floor (like a 100%-supported L-sit), so I wondered if I was far below average in this area.

Comment: The hip joint mobility to actually sit up on the floor with straight legs and a neutral spine is probably much more rare than the core strength otherwise required to perform the movement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's pretty do-able. I just did one right now to be sure. There's actually a bunch of muscles involved since you're locking your legs straight to help on the lever aspect.

The exercise is referred to as a [straight leg situp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AT6zWvOI6_o). Off the top of my head, I think some general full body conditioning stuff would be good, particularly the [flutter kick](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/HipFlexors/BWScissorKick.html), [turkish get up](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Kettlebell/KBTurkishGetup.html), and off course the [back squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BBSquat.html).

Comment: I can do one by swinging my arms overhead like he does in the video, so I'll get there. The flutter kick looks a lot healthier than training the situp directly.